# Find duplicate line items for each order

Tags: mysql

I have one table (orders) that has all the line items of each distinct order. 
I want to find out if any order has duplicate items (model) on it.

This is my working example which returns the proper values but only looks at one order and it takes 34 seconds to execute. I need to look at ~100 orders a day

```
SELECT ordnum, model
FROM orders
GROUP BY ordnum, model
HAVING (COUNT( * ) >1 && ordnum='1459387781')
```

I do have another table (orderinfo) where each record is one ordnum if needed to use.

There has to be a better way to query a table that has 31400 distinct ordnum but 1.3 million records
any guidance?

Comment: Try this: `select ordernum, model from orders where ordnum='1459387781' group by ordnum, model having count(*) > 1` and before you run that, create an index on ordernum and model like so: `create index idx_orders_num_model on orders (ordnum, model)`.

Answer (score 1):

All you need here is to group by ordNum, Model and return records having a count of model > 1 then..

HAVING executes after the select, so you have the count of records having the same model in an order.

The difference here is intead of count(*) which counts all records, we count the specific MODEL's

```
SELECT ORDNUM, model, count(Model)
FROM ORDERS
GROUP BY ORDNUM, MODEL
HAVING count(Model) > 1
```

As to the performance, if OrderNum and Model are part of a composite index this should be pretty quick.

Comment: `COUNT(*)` vs `COUNT(model)` makes no difference, except if `model` can be `null`, in which case `COUNT(model)` comes up `0` for a null `model`, where `COUNT(*)` would still count the number of rows with a null `model` value, so `COUNT(*)`, or maybe `COUNT(1)`, is by far the better choice.

Answer (score 0):

The statement does a full table scan

If you truly want it to only query one order, and the table has an index on `ordnum` (which seems likely), specify that in the `WHERE` clause, in which case there's no need to include `ordnum` in the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT model
FROM orders
WHERE ordnum = '1459387781'
GROUP BY model
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

If you *"need to look at ~100 orders a day"*, and you want to check todays orders, and your `orderinfo` table has an `orderdate`, then do this:

```
SELECT ordnum, model
FROM orders
WHERE ordnum in ( SELECT o.ordnum
                  FROM orderinfo o
                  WHERE o.orderdate = CURDATE() )
GROUP BY ordnum, model
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Will be very fast *if* `orderinfo` has index on `orderdate` *and* `orders` has index on `ordnum`.

Comment: I see what you are doing and maybe it is poor db design (it is not indexed) This query with just orderinfo.orddate='160330' times out (>60 second to execute) 'SELECT ordnum, model
FROM orders
WHERE ordnum in ( SELECT ordnum
                  FROM orderinfo
                  WHERE orddate = '160330' )
GROUP BY ordnum, model
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1'

Comment: sorry, i just figured out the back ticks

Comment: @SteveT Well, you have two choices: 1) Create index. 2) Live with performance of full table scan.